# Calculating a percentage of each row in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am making my first blazor app and I am using the out of the box app for weather forecast. I have placed the `TemperatureC` field in a database table and I have auto calculated the `TemperatureF`(this value is not stored in the DB and is done in the app). What I now want to do is have another column on the app for a `percentage` calculation where I will take the `TemperatureC` value per row and divide it by the sum of `TemperatureC` then multiply by 100 to get a % of 100. I am a bit confused how this will work and I could not find any resources to reference... does anyone know what could be done to obtain this?

WeatherForecast.cs

```
 public class WeatherForecast
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

        public double percentage => // I assume the calclation would happen here?
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How do you get a % of a temperature?  What does that mean?

Comment: Do you want to show the percentage of `TemperatureC` compared to the average `TemperatureC` in the list? e.g. temperature is 20, average temperature is 30 => that means temperature is 66,66% compared to the average.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, Just for example sake

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, Essentially, Just like how the TemperatureF is done, I would want Percentage o work in the same fashion but different calculation

Comment: so it wouldn't be the average but the sum

Comment: Your class only represents 1 Temperature. You are asking about multiple Temperatures. Maybe create a separate class for this.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you want to make can be done inside the razor component. You can calculate the sum of temperatures when the component is initialized and then use it inside foreach loop to calculate the percentage for each row.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>

            <th>Percentage</th>

            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
        {
            // calculate the percentage based on your formula
            float percentage = (float)forecast.TemperatureC / sumOfTemperatures * 100;

            <tr>
                <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>

                <td>@percentage<span>%</span></td>

                <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
    private int sumOfTemperatures;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
        
        // get the sum of all temperatures inside the list
        sumOfTemperatures = forecasts.Sum(f => f.TemperatureC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I hope it's better now.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, I have tried to play around with the code but the percentage always remains as a 0

Comment: Try to change the calculation to this: `float percentage = (float)forecast.TemperatureC / sumOfTemperatures * 100;`. At least one variable in the formula needs to be casted to float so that the result will be float. Still the number will be very small because it's divided by the sum which is big number.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, I tried to only fetch the sum values into the column and it worked... the reason it is showing 0 is because the TemperatureC is coming through as a 0... any idea why?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Okay I got it... Instead of forecast, I used `@context`... now a calculation can happen between tempc and the sum... but if I divide, it returns 0... all other operators work

Comment: Got it! adding the float worked!